# get some words in html using simple_html_dom

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I wanna get `zumbai`, `n`, and `something` from line of html below with simple_html_dom:

`<p>
    <div align="left" style="margin: 0.00mm 0.00mm ;">
    <p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 1.0em;">
    <b>zumbai</b> 
    <i>n</i> something
</p>
    </div>`

here's my code :

```
foreach($html->find('div.align') as $tag1) {
      foreach($tag1->parent()->find('p.style') as $tag2){
               $words1  = $tag2->first_child();
               $words11= $words1->plaintext;
               $words2  = $tag2->first_child()->first_child();
               $words22= $words2->plaintext;
      }
}
```

but it doesn't works. thank you :)

Comment: you have got two `<p>` tags with one closing!

Comment: the structure is all over the place

Comment: Just wonder if you have got 'zumbai' successfully?